# About checking a string is number or not

Tags: java

```
int s;

number2=input.next();

for (int i=0;i<number2.length();i++){ 

    s=(int)(number2.charAt(i));

    while ((s<48)||(s>57)){
    System.out.println("Enter the amount");
    number2=input.next();
    s=number2.charAt(i);    
     }

}
```

Using this code I can generate only a integer. If I want to generate a double with decimal, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `Integer.parseInt` or `Double.parseDouble` for parsing a stirng of integers or double values.

Comment: but I can only get integers. Suppose if I enter 123.56 then I have to enter that again.

Comment: @uddhabtiwari you can store it in variable

Comment: @JigarJoshi Can you show me that? I don't want to enter it as a integer or double but want it as a string. If I do input.nextInt or input.nextDouble and enter a string, it gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can cheat...

```
String text = "123";
boolean isDouble = false;
boolean isInt = false;
try {
    Double.parseDouble(text);
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(text);
        isInt = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        isDouble = true;
    }

    System.out.println("isInt = " + isInt);
    System.out.println("isDouble = " + isDouble);
} catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
    System.out.println(text + " is not a valid number");
}
```

`A123` outputs `A123 is not a valid number`...

`123` outputs...

```
isInt = true
isDouble = false
```

`123.321` outputs...

```
isInt = false
isDouble = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading your input from the user you can use `nextInt()`:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 0;
try{
    n = scan.nextInt();
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    //do here what you want to do in case it's not an int
}
```

don't forget to use try/catch in case the input is NOT an int (same applies to Juned's answer!).

Comment: But I dont want the program to exit if I enter string. in this case, if I enter a string, the program exits with error message.

Comment: @uddhabtiwari then catch that exception and handle it properly. To do so would be requesting a new input.

Comment: @Obicere I am just a basic Java programmer and just started to learn it. I don't know about catch and try syntax. Can you help me with that.

Comment: @uddhabtiwari I modified the code to demonstrate how to use try/catch